# Call Gallery Carousel with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

how can i hide my gallery carousel when i start up the page and only show if the user click on the button?

when i add the style display:none at the fixed-bar class, the gallery open but without images.

Here is my code:

Button:

```
<a onclick="$('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse"        style="margin-right:70px" data-transition="none" data-position-to="window">Paginas</a>
```

Gallery:

```
<div class="container demo-3">
            <div class="main">
                  <div class="fixed-bar">
              <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
     <li><a href="#p1"><img src="imagens/paginas/1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p2"><img src="imagens/paginas/2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p3"><img src="imagens/paginas/3.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p4"><img src="imagens/paginas/4.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5"><img src="imagens/paginas/5.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5"><img src="imagens/paginas/6.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5"><img src="imagens/paginas/7.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#p6"><img src="imagens/paginas/8.jpg" /></a></li>
                         </ul>
               </div>     
        </div>
  </div>
```

Script:

```
 $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
    minItems : 2
    } );
```

Comment: don't call the $( '#carousel' ).elastislide up until you click the button.

Comment: hmm how can i do that? thx for the help

Comment: onclick=" $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {minItems : 2} ); $('.fixed-bar').toggle('slow');"

Comment: have a bug.. when i click on the button the gallery open and close automatically.  when i click the second time it open with small pictures. when i cick the third time some pictures are hidden and only show some